# What is the current state-of-the-art in unsupervised cross-lingual representation learning?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, models, state-of-the-art

What is the current state-of-the-art in unsupervised cross-lingual representation learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post [Unsupervised Cross-lingual Representation Learning](https://ruder.io/unsupervised-cross-lingual-learning/) (2019), the related [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-4007.pdf) and [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1miPu0hkBFSRTAxP-Psg0xXOvAbVSJPhQXehMQdUI88I/edit#slide=id.g5cacfdb6b8_1_137) by Sebastian Ruder (a researcher currently at DeepMind) summarize what you are looking for. In fact, the authors write

> We will introduce researchers to **state-of-the-art** methods for constructing resource-light cross-lingual word representations and discuss their applicability in a broad range of downstream NLP applications, covering bilingual lexicon induction, machine translation (both neural and phrase-based), dialogue, and information retrieval tasks. We will deliver a detailed survey of the **current cutting-edge methods**, discuss best training and evaluation practices and usecases, and provide links to publicly available implementations, datasets, and pretrained models and word embedding collections.

Comment: Maybe later I will update this answer with a list of the SOTA methods/approaches.